# What are these fonts in a powerpoint pptx file?

Tags: apache-poi, powerpoint

I want to collect font information of a pptx with the help of Apache POI.

I basically search for string `typeface=` in the xmlObject of a powerpoint slide.

In some of my files, I can see a bunch of lines that contains the search string:

```
              <a:latin typeface="+mn-lt"/>
              <a:ea typeface="+mn-ea"/>
              <a:cs typeface="+mn-cs"/>
              <a:latin typeface="+mn-lt"/>
              <a:ea typeface="+mn-ea"/>
              <a:cs typeface="+mn-cs"/>
              <a:latin typeface="+mn-lt"/>
              <a:ea typeface="+mn-ea"/>
              <a:cs typeface="+mn-cs"/>
              <a:latin typeface="+mn-lt"/>
              <a:ea typeface="+mn-ea"/>
              <a:cs typeface="+mn-cs"/>
              <a:latin typeface="+mn-lt"/>
              <a:ea typeface="+mn-ea"/>
              <a:cs typeface="+mn-cs"/>
              <a:latin typeface="+mn-lt"/>
              <a:ea typeface="+mn-ea"/>
              <a:cs typeface="+mn-cs"/>
              <a:latin typeface="+mn-lt"/>
              <a:ea typeface="+mn-ea"/>
```

But if I check the file property dialog box, I can only see these fonts

[image]

There is no `+mn-lt` or `+mn-ea`

My questions:

Where do font faces like `+mn-ea` and `+mn-cs` come from?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The meaning of

```
<a:latin typeface="+mn-lt"/>
<a:ea typeface="+mn-ea"/>
<a:cs typeface="+mn-cs"/>
```

is as follows:

For latin text use first (default) given typeface in theme which is found there in `minorFont` - `latin` = `+mn-lt`:

For example `\ppt\theme\theme1.xml`:

```
...
<a:fontScheme name="...">
 ...
 <a:minorFont>
  <a:latin ... typeface="..."/>
  <a:ea ... typeface="..."/>
  <a:cs ... typeface="..."/>
  ...
 </a:minorFont>
</a:fontScheme>
...
```

Per default this will be `Calibri`.

For east asian text use first (default) given typeface in theme which is found there in `minorFont` - `ea` = `+mn-ea`.

For complex script text use first (default) given typeface in theme which is found there in `minorFont` - `cs` = `+mn-cs`.

OOXML schemes can have major fonts and minor fonts. Usually, major fonts are used for styles such as headings, whereas minor fonts are generally applied to body and paragraph text.

If `typeface="+mj-lt"` would be given, this would mean `majorFont` - `latin` in theme.